# Convert Linq expression to QueryExpression or FetchXML

Tags: linq, dynamics-crm, fetchxml

My ultimate goal is to convert a linq expression to fetch xml. I intend on using the fetch XML for custom grids in MS CRM 2011.

From this article, I can convert a QueryExpression to FetchXML http://mileyja.blogspot.com/2011/07/convert-queryexpression-to-fetchxml.html

But I don't know how to get a Linq expression to a QueryExpression. When I say a linq expression, I mean an object of type IQueryable<>.

Anyone had any experience with this or any know how?

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

The provided solution does not work for CRM2013 SDK assemblies as mentioned by Chielus.

For CRM2013 you can use this extension method:

```
public static class QueryProviderExtensions
{
    public static QueryExpression ToQueryExpression<T>(this IQueryable<T> items)
    {
        var queryProvider = items.Provider;

        var queryProviderType = queryProvider.GetType();
        var listType = typeof(List<>);

        var projectionType = queryProviderType.Assembly.GetType("Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider+Projection");
        var navigationSourceType = queryProviderType.Assembly.GetType("Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider+NavigationSource");
        var linkLookupType = queryProviderType.Assembly.GetType("Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider+LinkLookup");
        var linkLookupListType = listType.MakeGenericType(linkLookupType);

        object projection = null;
        object source = Activator.CreateInstance(navigationSourceType, new object[] { null, null });
        object linkLookups = Activator.CreateInstance(linkLookupListType);
        bool throwIfSequenceIsEmpty = false;
        bool throwIfSequenceNotSingle = false;

        object[] arguments = new object[6];
        arguments[0] = items.Expression;
        arguments[1] = throwIfSequenceIsEmpty;
        arguments[2] = throwIfSequenceNotSingle;
        arguments[3] = projection;
        arguments[4] = source;
        arguments[5] = linkLookups;

        var getQueryExpressionMethod = queryProviderType.GetMethod("GetQueryExpression", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, null, new[] {
                typeof(Expression), 
                typeof(bool).MakeByRefType(), 
                typeof(bool).MakeByRefType(),
                projectionType.MakeByRefType(),
                navigationSourceType.MakeByRefType(),
                linkLookupListType.MakeByRefType(),
            }, null);

        var queryExpression = (QueryExpression)getQueryExpressionMethod.Invoke(queryProvider, arguments);
        return queryExpression;
    }

    public static string ToXml(this QueryExpression queryExpression, IOrganizationService service)
    {
        var request = new QueryExpressionToFetchXmlRequest { Query = queryExpression };
        var response = (QueryExpressionToFetchXmlResponse)service.Execute(request);
        return response.FetchXml;
    }
}
```

Use it like so:

```
    // This can be any query
    var query = (from e in contactSet.Query()
                 where e.LastName.Contains("e")
                 select e);

    // This is where the magic happens
    var queryExpression = query.ToQueryExpression();

    // We can now add paging info
    queryExpression.PageInfo = new PagingInfo()
    {
        PageNumber = 1,
        Count = 50,
        ReturnTotalRecordCount = true
    };

    // This will create a QueryExpressionToFetchXmlRequest, not needed for paging.
    var xml = queryExpression.ToXml(service);

    // Perform the actual request 
    var collection = service.RetrieveMultiple(queryExpression);
```

More details here:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0026f1de-bc10-428d-ad15-18d34315c814/convert-linq-query-to-fetchxml-sdk-2013?forum=crm

Answer (score 3):

you can use reflection to get `QueryExpression`, from `IQuerable<T>` get the provider and call Translate method on it.

here is extension method I'm using:

```
public static QueryExpression ToQueryExpression(this IQueryable @this)
{
    var provider = @this.Provider;
    var translateMethod = provider.GetType().GetMethod("Translate");
    var query = (QueryExpression)translateMethod.Invoke(provider, new object[] { @this.Expression });

    return query;
}
```

if you use some sort of dynamic wrapper for reflection in C# like [ExposedObject](http://exposedobject.codeplex.com/) you can just do smth like that:

```
public static QueryExpression ToQueryExpression(this IQueryable @this)
{
    dynamic provider = ExposedObject.From(@this.Provider);

    return provider.Translate(@this.Expression);
}
```

as for fetch you need to have `QueryExpression` and then issue a request `QueryExpressionToFetchXmlRequest` that returns `QueryExpressionToFetchXmlResponse` response, which have property `FetchXml`.

Comment: This is broken in Dynamics CRM 2013.
See this blogpost for a supported alternative: http://www.hashtagcrm.com/?p=157

Answer (score 0):

calling ToString() on the LINQ expression should return the FetchXML

Comment: I tried this but it just returns the object type name. I found references to this but only for CRM 4.0.